# GC in Server Mode Not Collecting the Memory

Tags: garbage-collection

IIS hosted WCF service is consuming Large memory like 18 GB and the server has slowed down.

I Analyzed Mini dump file and it shows only 1 GB or active objects. I understand the GC is not clearing the memory and GC must be running in server mode in 64 bit System. Any idea why the whole computer is stalling and app is taking huge memory?

Comment: You should give more details in your question. How do you know it is using 18GB and how did you generate and analyze your "mini dump file". When you say "the whole computer is stalling", are other applications on the server slow too?

Comment: Yes, the other windows services failing to execute requests in the queue. I have Collected Performance counter and mini dump from Task Manager.  I found the root cause of it and got the solution for now.  .NET 4.5 has addressed this issue.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GC was running on Server Mode it was configured for better performance.  I Understand GC running in Server mode will have a performance improvement because the GC's will not be triggered frequently due to high available memory and in server mode it will have high limit on memory usage. Here the problem was when the high limit is reached for the process CLR triggered the GC and it was trying to clear the Huge 18 GB of memory in one shot, so it was using 90% of system resource and rest applications were lagging.

We tried restarting but it was forever going so We had to kill the process. and now with Workstation mode GC smooth and clean. The only difference is response time has some delay due to GC after 1.5 GB allocation.

One more info: .NET 4.5 version has revision regarding this which has resolved this issue in GC.